# Example of turning nonautonomous system of ODEs to autonomous system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am reading Chicone's book and it mentions that you can reduce an $n$th order differential equation into a system of first order equations, and gives an example. Nevertheless, there's no example of how you convert a nonautonomous differential equation to an autonomous one. How does this work, say with $x' = x + t$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You fix $y = t$ and $x = x$ so that $y' = 1$ and you have the system
\begin{align}
x' &= x + y, \\
y' &= 1,
\end{align}
with initial condition $y(0) = 0$, and $x(0) = x_0$.

In general, if $y \in \mathbb R^d$, $f\colon \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$, and you have the ODE $y' = f(t, y)$ with IC $y(0) = y_0 \in \mathbb R^d$, you can make the change of variable $Y = (y, t)$ and $F(Y) = (f(Y_{d+1}, Y_{1:d}), 1)$ to get the autonomous ODE $Y' = F(Y)$ with initial condition $Y(0) = (y_0, 0)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4221034/transfer-function-of-a-linear-non-autonomous-system