# Convert Second Order ODE into first order linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Let $x(t)$ be the distance from the equilibrium position of a spring of mass m with a variable coefficient of stiffness $k(x+x^3)$. The motion of the spring is described by the ODE
$$mx''=-k(x+x^3), t>0$$ where k is a constant.

The differential equation could be written
$$x''=-ω^2(x+x^3)=0, ω=\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$$

The question is how can I write the ODE as a first-order 2x2 system? I thought I would put $x'=v$ and then I would have
$$v'=-ω^2(x+x^3), x'=v$$.
But I am not sure

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @G.Gare     The question is how can I write the ODE as a first-order 2x2 system?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3412149/example-of-turning-nonautonomous-system-of-odes-to-autonomous-system-of-odes/3412153#3412153

Comment: Yes, your using the derivative to get a state vector and its first-order system is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if I understood it correctly, but you can reduce the order of the proposed ODE as follows:
\begin{align*}
x'' = -\omega^{2}(x + x^{3}) & \Longleftrightarrow x''x' = -\omega^{2}(x + x^{3})x'\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 2x''x' = -\omega^{2}(2x + 2x^{3})x'\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x')^{2} = -\omega^{2}\left(x^{2} + \frac{x^{4}}{2}\right) + c
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: The question is how can I write the ODE as a first-order 2x2 system? I thought i would put $x'=v$ and then i would have $v'=-ω^2(x+x^3), x'=v$
But I am not sure

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos that is correct, why not?